# State and prove a theorem that gives a formula for $f′(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis

State and prove a theorem that gives a formula for $f′(x_0)$ when
$f = f_n\circ f_{n−1}\circ\cdots\circ f_2\circ f_1.$
(Be sure to state all the hypotheses that you need.)

Comment: This sounds like something dumped here from a set of exercises. A better idea is to tell us why this problem interests you, what you have been able to do with it, where you get stuck, and so on.

Comment: As Cameron Buie mentions, this is essentially an iterated chain rule. I would try induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: This is a generalization of chain rule, and works basically the same way.